# Contains the representation with multiplicity n

Tags: representation-theory

In a problem I'm asked to prove that a representation contains the trivial representation with multiplicity $n$.

I'm a little confused. What exactly does "contain" mean and "multiplicity"?

Does it mean that the representation has $n$ (non-equivalent) trivial representations as subrepresentations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A representation $V$ of a group $G$ is said to contain the trivial representation with multiplicity $n,$ if the space $V^G$ of $G$-invariants (i.e $\{v|v=gv\text{ for all } g \in G\}$) has dimension $n.$

Comment: (+1) But I think that strictly speaking this recipe works only when we are in a situation where we know that the representations are semisimple. For example, when Maschke's theorem applies. Normally (I think) multiplicity is about how many times the trivial representation appears as a composition factor. For example if $G$ is cyclic of order $p$, and $k$ is a field of characteristic $p$, then $G$ may act via matrices of the form $$\pmatrix{1&x\cr0&1\cr}$$ on the space $k^2$. Here the $G$-invariants form a 1-dim. subspace, but the multiplicity of the trivial rep as a composition factor is two.